# explode and then insert to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, explode

I'm just confused with how to explode the string to insert into the database individually.

My code:

```
$mymotives = "Entrega de Documentos, Orientacion, Username y Password, Convalidacion";          
$ExplodeMotives = explode(", ", $mymotives);
foreach ($ExplodeMotives as  $value) {
    $queryAdd = "INSERT INTO StuSelectCateg (attendedBy, personName, personLast, depName, categoryName, timeOut) 
                 VALUES ('".$_SESSION["nomEmpleado"]. " " . $_SESSION["appEmpleado"]."', '".$_SESSION['estNombre']."', '".$_SESSION['estApellido']."', '".$_SESSION['concentracion']."', '$value', '$stuTOut')";
    mysqli_query($con, $queryAdd);
}
```

I want my output to be in my database like this

```
Table | Category
-----------------------------
1     | Entrega de Documentos
2     | Username y Password
3     | Convalidacion
```

Comment: This just dosent do anything  my output in my database would be Entrega de Documentos, Orientacion, Username y Password, Convalidacion the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      $mymotives = "Entrega de Documentos, Orientacion, Username y Password, Convalidacion";
      $ExplodeMotives = explode(", ", $mymotives);
      foreach ($ExplodeMotives as  $value)
      {
           $queryAdd[] = "INSERT INTO StuSelectCateg (attendedBy, personName, personLast, depName, categoryName, timeOut) VALUES ('".$_SESSION["nomEmpleado"]. " " . $_SESSION["appEmpleado"]."', '".$_SESSION['estNombre']."', '".$_SESSION['estApellido']."', '".$_SESSION['concentracion']."', '$value', '$stuTOut')";
      }
     mysqli_query($con, $queryAdd);
?>
```

you can change variabel queryAdd to an array like a bove.

Comment: this will make my data like that?

Comment: I get this error Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BackUP\Empleados.php on line 104

Answer (score 0):

Wow thank god I did it by my self thanks either way even tho it was wrong

> `$mymotives=$stuMotives;
>       $ExplodeMotives = explode(", ", $mymotives);
>         foreach ($ExplodeMotives as  $value)
>         {
>              $queryAdd = "INSERT INTO StuSelectCateg (attendedBy, personName, personLast, depName, categoryName, timeOut) VALUES ('".$_SESSION["nomEmpleado"]. " " . $_SESSION["appEmpleado"]."', '$stuName', '$stuApell', '$stuDepart', '$value', '$stuTOut')";
>        mysqli_query($con, $queryAdd); 
>         }`

Comment: This is bad because you are doing multiple insert calls when you can do everything in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Replying rather late but would like to point out that with the other solutions you will be creating multiple connections to mysql when you can do all the inserts in one sql query. Use my solution below.

```
<?php
      $string = "Entrega de Documentos, Orientacion, Username y Password, Convalidacion";
      $categories = explode(", ", $string);

      $query = "INSERT INTO StuSelectCateg (attendedBy, personName, personLast, depName, categoryName, timeOut) VALUES ";

      foreach ($ExplodeMotives as  $value)
      {
           $query_vals[]  =   "('" 
                          .$_SESSION["nomEmpleado"]. "', '" 
                          .$_SESSION["appEmpleado"]."',  '" 
                          .$_SESSION['estNombre']."', '"
                          .$_SESSION['estApellido']."', '"
                          .$_SESSION['concentracion']."', '"
                          .$value."', '"
                          .$stuTOut. "')";
      }
     $query = $query . implode(", ", $query_vals );
     mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
```

This will do a query like inserting all the rows in one mysql insert call:

```
INSERT INTO tableName
   (column1,column2,column3,column4)
VALUES
  ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4'),
  ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4'),
  ('value1' , 'value2', 'value3','value4');
```

Answer (score 0):

*take string data and explode and store into database*

```
$str = "abcde@gmail.com,dfkjp@gmail.com,veer@gmail.com,kalll@gmail.com";
    $emails=explode(",",$str);
    $key=1;
    foreach($emails as $email){
    //echo $email.'<br>';
    $sql="INSERT INTO `block_simplenotify`(`id`,`email`) VALUES ('$key++','$email')";
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.